# Python Classes - No calls? One Loop?

Tags: python, class, loops, inheritance

I have recently started using classes and have two questions.

1. I know that like a function, python has to read through all class lines once before any calls are made or initiated. 
   >
   EDIT>>>So I wonder, is it possible to run a whole program within this first call python automatically self initiates? 
   >
   Ie. Run an entire program strictly out of classes without making any calls or instances.
2. The other thing I was curious about was whether or not there is a way to run a loop out of a single class, such as 'while' or even 'for x in y'. Essentially, what I am curious about is whether there is a way to 'inherit' a running loop.

Example:

```
class Loop:
    def __init__(self, exit=0):
        print "loop initiated"
        self.exit = exit

    def myloop(self): ##This was edited
        while self.exit == 0:
            print "look at me, I'm Looping!"

class Clock(Loop):

    def loopexit(self):
        print "one day I will close that loop"
        pass

    def tick(self):
        print "who knows what I might do one day"
        pass

aclock = Clock(exit=0)

alcock.myloop() #This was edited
aclock.loopexit() #This was edited
```

Bare in mind, this example will obviously not work as the exit call cannot be made whilst the myloop() is running.
>
EDIT>>> I included this example to show how I would theoretically like to close this loop although it is obvious that it will not work. Basically, I'm trying to find a solution closer to this example.
>
I also realize it is possible to call exit from inside the myloop(), but remember this is mostly a question about inheritance.

Suppose, for simplicity sake, that closing from inside myloop() was not an option.

The only make-shift solution I have been able to come up with is using *args as an argument in myloop(), but I would prefer something less dependant on myloop().

Any and all feedback appreciated,

Thankyah

Comment: If you have two separate questions, they should be asked in two separate posts.  That said, I'm having trouble understanding your first question, but you seem to be confusing parsing & function definition with execution.

Comment: I can't understand either of your questions.  What is "this single self initiated python loop"?  What do you intend for your code example to do?

Comment: I edited it for greater clarity. As far as the first question goes, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16885737/why-does-a-class-get-called-when-not-initiated-python

Comment: BrenBarn, I clarified "this singl self initiated..." and the purpose of the example in the edit.

Comment: @NickSimas: If your question is "can you put all your code inside a class body", the answer is basically yes, but there's no point in doing that, since if you're not going to use the class, why have it at all?  Your second question is still unclear.  You say it is supposed to show how you would like to close the loop, but I don't understand at all what part of that code you intend to close what loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for your firs question:
yes one can make a Python program without using classes or functions at all:
all satements are executed in theorder they are encountered

2) you certainly are mixing some concepts there, but generally
"yes" - one could stop a loop running in another method if running
in parallell to that loop, in a separate thread,
or using some asynchronous form of programing (so that
code in the other method gets executed while the loop is running)
Thishowever has nothing to do with inheritance. (Note though that
your specific example does not start the loop, and also,
you'd have a name conflict with `self.exit` there) -

Comment: Thanks, jsbueno. What I am trying to ask is whether or not there is a way to structure a loop so that it could be closed without any parallel processing. Threading may actually be the answer I am looking for.

Comment: Also, as to the first questions, I meant write a whole program using only classes without any lines of code outside of the classes written. So far I have been able to make it work by calling classes from inside a class.

Comment: Yes, you cna run a program entirely in class bodies. A program out of functions on the module body would already be an awful thing. A program in the body of classes would be even more awful - but it would work.